# Table not initialized issue using @tf.function while loading TF hub model

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-hub

I am trying to load the Tf hub model and predict the output using @tf.function decorator. It is throwing **tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError:  Table not initialized.** error.

TF version - 2.1.0

TF hub Version - 0.8.0

**Note**: It is working without using @tf.function decorator

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

image_tensor = tf.constant(2.0, shape=[1, 298, 298, 3])


@tf.function
def run_function(method, args):
    return method(args)


detector = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/google/openimages_v4/ssd/mobilenet_v2/1", 
signature_outputs_as_dict=True)
detector_output = run_function(detector, image_tensor)
class_names = detector_output["detection_class_entities"]
print(class_names)
```

Can anyone know the reason why it is not working with @tf.function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a TensorFlow V1 hub model in `hub.KerasLayer` which is to be used for tf2.0 models

In TensorFlow hub, you can find a toggle button to view tf hub models for specific TensorFlow versions.

[image]

To make it work using `hub.KeralLayer`, change the URL to either of the following tf2.0 mobilenet versions

1. https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/mobilenet_v2/classification/4
2. https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/mobilenet_v2_050_96/classification/4

or if you have to use the exact URL as in your example. Use `hub.Module` instead of `hub.KeralLayer`